# Returning value after invoking event in C#

Tags: c#, events

I am working on a project, where I have to invoke a method when a value gets below a certain threshold. This event then writes some information to the user.
I have decided to put it in the setter, as it should be displayed when the user tries to get information.
The problem is that I still want to get something afterwards (as it is a getter), but I get stackoverflow and I can see that the getter is called many times. I thought this was weird, since the .invoke should only invoke the event and then move on. So how can i move further from the invoke, instead of having it go back to the beginning of the setter every time it is called,

This is the current setter:

```
get 
    {
    if (_balance <= BalanceThreshold)
       UserBalanceNotification.Invoke(this,BalanceThreshold);
    return _balance; 
    }
```

And this is the general event:

```
public delegate void UserBalanceNotification(User user, int balanceThreshold);
```

As this is a more general question I doubt more code snippet would support it

Comment: Don't use the getter for calling methods. You're not in control who is requesting the properties value

Comment: Use the field instead of the property to avoid stackoverflows

Comment: How can I use the fields.  @JeroenvanLangen ?

Comment: I suggest you create a boolean property which hold the information if the balance is below the threshold. Also you should call the `UserBalanceNotification?.Invoke();`  (without arguments just a notification) in the setter. The eventhandler can check the `bool BelowThreshold {get;set;}` it self.